# Search with more than 5 Million recods With Posgres

Tags: postgresql, index, full-text-search, filtered-index

Search to be implemented for currently developing a project which is being developed using Spring Boot and Postgres.

The search table has at least 8 columns, all the columns are used in the search filtering. For this, how many indices need to be created? What type of index needs to be created?

There will be at least 1M records in the table. Is Postgres enough with better indices? or need to choose any other NoSQL like Elastic Search?

Please share your thoughts and experience on this.

**EDITED**

[image]

please refer to the above screen capture for my search mock design. All the combinations of each column would be used for filtering. If so 8 power 8 would be 40320. So do I need to create 40320 indices? FYI: I have few more searches same like this.
Since I have many columns, so I guess there would be more indices to be created which is not the right way to do. in this case, `Elastic Search` is better to choose or `Postgres` itself serves the purpose

Comment: Don't ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66526980/search-with-more-than-5-million-recods-with-posgres) in several forums.

Comment: With a small table like that, performance isn't the major criteria I would say. You should first check if the built-in full text search supports all the _features_ you need.

Comment: Under most circumstances these days a few million records is not large for any good DB if well indexed. Beyond that we'd need a lot more details before being able to recommend an indexing strategy or a particular database.

Comment: @ThomsonIgnesious You are still missing some important information that we requested, such as "*examples of specific queries you need to support*". For example if your searches are always equality based, e.g. `WHERE PID = 123 AND TID = 56` then the type of index you need could be completely different than if you need to do wildcard matching such as `WHERE Roles LIKE 'RoleA%'`. The more examples, the better please.

Comment: @J.D. mostly it will be full-text using `LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

When you need 1M records out of 5M, no index will be of use, better scan the full table.

Comment: Even if the data request is so large that a table scan is inevitable (because the post-index-search lookups would be more expensive than the scan) then wide indexes may help considerably at the expense of storage space. Also indexes may help if the data was requested with an `ORDER BY` to avoid spooling to disk in order to sort.

Comment: So you agree that the chances an index may be of use, are very slim?

Comment: No, just that single-column non-clustered indexes are unlikely to be terribly useful, especially if there is no simple ordering use for them. We need much more detail than the question gives to say anything at all concrete, but I suspect there would be an indexing strategy that would help.

Comment: @DavidSpillett - I thought that PostgreSQL didn't have clustered indexes?

Comment: @Vérace - it doesn't as such, but it does support wide indexes which would convey the relevant benefits here (removing the need for further table lookups in some cases). Though be careful with columns that are `INCLUDE`d rather than being part of the indexed values as postgres has some subtleties there (see https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2019-04/include-columns-in-btree-indexes#compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

**NoSQL** and **ElasticSearch** are neither more performant database systems than any other modern relational database system, such as **PostgreSQL**, when talking about amount of data. **NoSQL** is an option of choice when you have a very dynamic schema or lack thereof, and **ElasticSearch** is useful for tokenizing large bodies of text to make them more *easily* searchable, which may very well be relevant to your use-case.

Unfortunately your post is a little unclear to be able to provide a concrete answer, as we'd need more details such as your Table's schema, some example search queries you anticipate will be ran, and some example data you plan to store in the table and would be returned by those queries.

As others have pointed out, if your table is only 1 million records, 5 records, or even 100 million records, proper structuring and indexing will provide you with performance on PostgreSQL, no problem. But without the details I mentioned above, we can't recommend what kind of structuring and indexing you'll need, most optimally. For example, a table with only 3 columns has at least 11 possible different combinations of index definitions that can be created (since field order in the definition matters). But it's unrealistic and possibly would affect performance negatively to store 11 indexes on a table of 3 columns, rather it's important to define your indexes based on the queries being executed against the table. The indexes definitions depend on the queries that are ran more so than the columns that exist in the table themselves.

Comment: thanks, I am building the search functionalities now, I will get the search query, with analyze details for better index

Comment: All my doubt is. I have 8 columns in the table. how many indexes do I need to create? An index for each column is alone enough or compound indices required for the combination of columns for a number of possibilities?

Comment: @ThomsonIgnesious: that depends on how you want to search. If you always want to search in all 8 columns at the same time, a single index on the concatenated values would be enough. If you want to search in each column individually you need 8 different indexes.

Comment: @ThomsonIgnesious This is why my answer requests the specific search queries you expect to run. It doesn't matter how many columns you have, rather it matters how those columns are used in your queries. The answer to *"how many indexes are needed for an 8 column table"* could literally be anywhere between 0 and ~1,000+ (though 1,000 is unrealistic). Unfortunately it's just not enough information to solve the problem with a meaningful answer.

Comment: @J.D.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/foiv9mkqxl4h23n/Screenshot%20from%202021-03-09%2011-46-24.png?dl=0
please refer to the above screen capture for my search mock design.  All the combinations of each column would be used for filtering. If so 8 power 8 would be  40320. So do I need to create 40320 indices?

Comment: @ThomsonIgnesious - you should edit any extra detail into your question as it can get "lost" in the comments and so not be seen by others (who might be able to help, or might later be seeking the same help).

Comment: @ThomsonIgnesious As David mentioned, please put all updates in your original question's post. I'll look into and will update my answer when I get a chance. The possible potential number of indexes is even greater than 40,320 without knowing your queries, but realistically no one would recommend to create that many as that would actually hurt performance. Generally you should try to stick to about 5 indexes at most per table, but this is a loose recommendation and will vary for each situation.

Comment: @J.D. I have updated the description